# Last character in a memo field

Tags: .net, loops, special-characters, memo

I am looping character through a memo field but I do not know how to stop the looping. Is there an End-of-field value like the EOF character? Is there a better way to determine the end of a memo field?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `foreach` you don't need to worry about it...

```
        string memo = "test";
        foreach (var x in memo.ToCharArray())
        {
            // you code here
        }
```

Comment: I am not familar with the foreach function. What would be the target for the foreach? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Why the use of `ToCharArray`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "memo field." Do you mean a string? If so, then you can access the `Length` property:

```
string memo = "hello, world";
for (int i = 0; i < memo.Length; ++i)
{
    char c = memo[i];
    // do what you want with the character.
}
```

Or you can use the `foreach` as was suggested previously:

```
foreach (var c in memo)
{
    // do what you want with the character
}
```